# changing color of a row in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a datagridview which displays a table "items (Item_desc, quantity, unit_price)".

i need to change the color of the row whose quantity value is less than say 10.

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow dgvr in dgv.Rows)
{
    int  quantity=int32.Parse(dgv.Cells[10].Value.ToString()) ;
    if( quantity <10)
    {
        .....
    }
}
```

Comment: datagrid in wpf has no property as "Rows".

what to use in place of it.

Comment: sorry it's for winForm.this link will help you :http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/162833/how-to-get-datagrid-particular-cell-value-in-wpf

Answer (score 0):

Create a property in your class say `IsQuantityLessThanTen` and use that in your trigger (in Style of DataGridRow) to change the bakground row.

Also, you can use the [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) in case you don't want to go for creating property. Ideally this is how it should be done otherwise you have to explicitly raise the `PropertyChanged` for your property whenever Quantity proeprty changes to reflect back it on UI.

```
public bool IsQuantityLessThanTen
{
   get
   {
      return Quantity < 10;
   }
}


<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsQuantityLessThanTen}" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
           </DataTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
     </Style>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
......
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: i am new to wpf and have never used such property methods.

is there any other method?

Comment: What is ItemsSource for your dataGrid?

Comment: i am using a datatable as the itemsource.
datatable is populated using sqldataadapter.